# Impress.js : texts and images look blurry

Tags: javascript, html, css, blurry, impress.js

With [Impress.js](https://github.com/bartaz/impress.js), my texts and my images look blurry.

See the next screenshot where CSS is disabled but Impress.js is enabled :

[image]

And now see the next screenshot where Impress.js and CSS are disabled :

[image]

Why are they blurry ?

This is my configuration :

```
<div id="Model-2" class="step" data-x="117000" data-rotate="20">
    <h2>Backbone.Model</h2>
    <p>On peut préciser des valeurs par défaut</p>
    <img src="img/18.png">
</div>
```

Comment: I think this has to do something with hw acceleration or (-prefix-)perspective css declaration. At least I've run into similar blurring problems with it. Check through inspector whether those elements have eg. perspective set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because impress.js uses translate3d and aliasing will automatically be disabled in favor of performance, unfortunately there is no quick fix.